# Updating records by ID mysql and php

Tags: php

I am learning php at the moment so I have set myself a task to create a to do list.

I have got to a point where I can add a record, show that record or records. Now I am wanting to edit that record and also delete that record but am a little confused. So I guess I need to target the unique ID of that record in order to make changes to update or delete.

Here is what I put together to get me started:

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE items SET content='blah blah blah' WHERE id=id");

if (isset($_POST['content'])) {
   mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE items SET content='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['content'])."' WHERE id='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['id'])."' ");
}

header('Location: index.php');

mysqli_close($con);
```

That is hooked up to a form:

```
    <form action="insertupdate.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value ="1">
Content: <input type="text" name="content">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

I also created a column with three status's to either 0 = deleted 1 = active 2 = complete

I am a little stuck and just need a pointer more than anything.

Answer (score 1):

Your query should look like this:

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE items SET content='blah blah blah' WHERE id=1");
```

**EDIT**

```
if (isset($_POST['content'])) {
   mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE items SET content='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['content'])."' WHERE id=1");
}
```

**However you should learn  [How to prevent SQL-injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1) to make your code secure.**

**EDIT2**

```
<form action="insertupdate.php" method="post">
Content: <input type="text" name="content">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value = "1">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

and

```
if (isset($_POST['content'])) {
   mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE items SET content='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['content'])."' WHERE id=".intval($_POST['id']));
}
```

Comment: Oh brilliant so that changed it, now the confusion I really have it that I am setting the content to change within the query, how do I target allow it from my form to change from what I enter in the text box?

Comment: Ok cool, now again to further this, you can see this target id=1, how do I make it target the item that I am targeting?

Comment: You need to have in your form id you want to edit. For example `<input type="hidden" name="id" value ="1">` and then change in query ` into `$_POST['id]` using the same technique I showed above

Comment: That seems to have a caused problem where by now it has changed all the items to the same...there was a > missed off. So now it updates only eh first item, how can I make it target the items Io am wanting to update by their id?

Comment: This code should work, you simple need to put value of record id you want to change. So in PHP you can do `$idToChange = 5;` and then in your form: `<input type="hidden" name="id" value = "<?php echo $idToChange; ?>">`

Comment: Im struggling to understand a little :/ so will that target item 5?

Comment: Yes, it should change item with id = 5

Comment: Ok so I dont wanna specifically target an item I need it know that when I click edit item it know it is that one it needs to edit see my post above of the index page.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot help you more with this. This forum is for help with question and you cannot edit your question 3 or 4 times to get new answers. You should also learn basics of PHP on your own

Answer (score 1):

a varchar type value must be written in single or double quote.